# Why isn't this Matrix code outputting?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, matrix, split

I'm writing this code to format a string of numbers into a matrix. I can't get it to output the formatted matrix. I need some help.

here is my main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "A = [5 4 1; 3 6 1; 2 3 9]";
    Console.WriteLine("Original text: '{0}'", text);

    Matrix calling = new Matrix(text);
    calling.GetMatrix2(text);
}
```

and this is my class:

```
class Matrix
{
    private string textt;

    public Matrix(string text1)
    {
        textt = text1;        
    }

    public string[,] GetMatrix2(string text)
    {
        char[] delimiter1 = { '[', ']' };
        char[] delimiter2 = { ';' };
        char[] delimiter3 = { ' ' };
        string[][] words = text.Split(delimiter1)[1]
                               .Split(delimiter2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                               .Select(x => x.Split(
                                        delimiter3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                               .ToArray();

        string[,] matrix = new string[words.Length, words[0].Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < words[i].Length; ++j)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = words[i][j];
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

I'm I calling it wrong? I thought that if I return "matrix"(in the method) and then call that method "Getmatrix2" then it would display the resulting matrix.

Comment: [Write a better title based on your specific problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/158761)

Comment: *" I can't get it to output anything."* Really? Even `Original text:`?

Comment: You have only one `Console.WriteLine()`. Do you mean to output something else too, perhaps after your `GetMatrix2()`?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that if I return "matrix"(in the method) and then call that
>   method "Getmatrix2" then it would display the resulting matrix.

Why would it? You're not printing anything out anywhere, not to debug nor the console, you're only converting the jagged array into a 2D array. Simply invoking a method will not print out it's values for no reason.

What you're missing is an iteration over the 2D array and printing out of each value. If you want it to look like a NxM matrix:

```
var matrix = calling.GetMatrix2(text);
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", matrix[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This yields:

```
5 4 1 
3 6 1 
2 3 9
```

Comment: Does that format into a 3x3 Matrix? I tried putting that in my main and it gave me a single column of the numbers.

Comment: @LebronJamess No, this simply prints out the values one by one, appending a new line after each value. You can easily format it so it prints 3 values for each row.

Comment: How do I format it? because I wrote another code that was smaller than this but basically did the same thing. I'm stuck on the formatting part.

Comment: @LebronJamess How do you want it printed out? Like your original text?

Comment: A 3X3 matrix:  3 rows by 3 column

Comment: Ahh. I see. Thank you for your help and patience. I will try to apply this to my other code that I wrote as well.